# Symfony2.0 - InvalidArgumentException

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, invalidargumentexception

I'm having a little bit of trouble with symfony 2.3 and am hoping you can help me out.

I don't really know what i did wrong but out of the sudden I got these errors and now i can't get rid of them.

Error 1:

```
InvalidArgumentException: [WARNING 1549] failed to load external entity "file:///C:/wamp/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd" (in n/a - line 0, column 0)
[WARNING 3084] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'file:///C:/wamp/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd'. Skipping the import. (in in_memory_buffer - line 8, column 0)
[ERROR 1845] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}container': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in file:///C:/wamp/www/Symfony/web/ - line 5, column 0)
```

Error2:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to parse file "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\web.xml".
```

I've tried to remove what i thought was causing these errors (i tried to clean the cache also) but none of that worked.

I am guessing that i must have something wrong in a twig or xlf file, as these errors appeared after i modified only those files, but can't find out what i'm doing wrong in those files (to me all of what i did looks fine)

I can post the files if u guys need them.

**EDIT:**

twig file:

```
{%  extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ 'myAccount'|trans }}{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/account/css/myProfile.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="profile-hor-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills profile-menu-font">
        <li class="active profile-hor-nav-element">
            <a href="#">{{ 'gameInfo'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="profile-hor-nav-element">
            <a href="#">{{ 'accountInfo'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="profile-ver-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked profile-menu-font">
        <li class="active profile-ver-nav-element">
            <a href="#">{{ 'matchHistory'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="profile-ver-nav-element">
            <a href="#">{{ 'statistics'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="profile-ver-nav-element">
            <a href="#">{{ 'charObj'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

en.xlf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>registrationMessage</source>
                <target>Enroll and fight for glory on the battlefields.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>registrationSuccessMessage</source>
                <target>You will receive an email to finish your registration</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="3">
                <source>gameInfo</source>
                <target>Game information</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="4">
                <source>accountInfo</source>
                <target>Account information</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="5">
                <source>matchHistory</source>
                <target>Match history</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="6">
                <source>statistics</source>
                <target>Statistics</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="7">
                <source>charObj</source>
                <target>Characters and Objects</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

fr.xlf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>registrationMessage</source>
                <target>Inscrivez-vous et combattez pour la gloire sur les champs de bataille.</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="2">
                <source>registrationSuccessMessage</source>
                <target>Vous allez recevoir un email pour completer votre inscription</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="3">
                <source>gameInfo</source>
                <target>Informations en jeu</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="4">
                <source>accountInfo</source>
                <target>Informations du compte</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="5">
                <source>matchHistory</source>
                <target>Historique des parties</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="6">
                <source>statistics</source>
                <target>Statistiques</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="7">
                <source>charObj</source>
                <target>Personnages et Objets</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**EDIT 2:**

So after checking, I actually have the version 2.4.0 BETA1 of symfony

I'm running wampserver with apache 2.4.4, php 5.4.16 and mysql 5.6.12

Hope you can help me,

Thank you beforehand for your help.

Comment: _I've tried to remove what i thought was causing these errors_ - what exactly did you remove?

Comment: just the things i had added in the twig and xlf files...

Comment: Ill post those files in a few moments

Comment: Did your really cleaned your cache? You may just delete the cache folders (notthe cache folder itself, only the folders in there). Would you mind posting your complete setup (version, webserver etc.)?\

Comment: I used the php app/console cache:clear command (dev mode). Ill edit my post and add what you asked for now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why but after restaring the computer (so wampserver as well) the problem was gone.
If you guys have any idea why is that, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: On first, I did not believe this would work. Seems like a stupid thing, but when I tried it actually worked! :P

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar error, and it was so simple.

Your problem could be in the extension used in your dependencyInjection Bundle.
In my case, I was loading yml files with an xmlFileLoader, like this:

```
<?php

namespace xxx\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class xxxUserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('user.yml');
        $loader->load('forms.yml');               
    }
}
```

I was loading yml Files, so I've had to use an YmlFileLoader instead of XmlFileLoader.

Additional information here: https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/symfony2-symfonycomponentdependencyinjectionexceptioninvalidargumentexception-unable-to-parse-file/